# Flash - Pause Game ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm only a beginner and this code is somewhere in the internet that I just want to learn
This is a snake game, I want to pause a game using spacebar keyboard
I don't know how to pause a game someone please help

```
import flash.ui.*;

    public class Snake extends MovieClip
    {

        private var _Paused:Boolean = false
        private var score, life, framesElapsed:Number;
        private var p1speedX, p1speedY:Number;
        private var spacePressed, readyToMove, gotoWin, gotoLose:Boolean;
        private var left,right,up,down:Boolean;
        private var snakes:Array;
        private var mcFood:Food;

        public function Snake()
        {

        }

        //All Start Functions
        public function startMenu()
        {
            stop();
            btnStartGame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoStartGame);
            btnHowToPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHowToPlay);
        }

        public function startHowToPlay()
        {
            btnBack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMenu);
        }

        public function startWin()
        {
            btnBack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMenu);
        }

        public function startLose()
        {
            btnBack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMenu);
        }

        public function startGame()
        {           
            score = 0;
            life = 3;
            framesElapsed = 0;
            p1speedX = 1; //snakek starts moving right
            p1speedY = 0;
            up = false;
            down = false;
            left = false;
            right = false;
            spacePressed = false;
            readyToMove = false;
            gotoWin = false;
            gotoLose = false;
            snakes = new Array();

            //Create 1st body part of snake and push it into the array
            var snakeHead = new SnakePart();
            snakeHead.x = 400;
            snakeHead.y = 300;
            snakes.push(snakeHead);
            addChild(snakeHead);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownHandler);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpHandler);

            stage.focus = this;
        }

        //All Goto Functions
        private function gotoStartGame(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            btnStartGame.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoStartGame);
            btnHowToPlay.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHowToPlay);
            gotoAndStop("game");
        }

        private function gotoHowToPlay(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            btnStartGame.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoStartGame);
            btnHowToPlay.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoHowToPlay);
            gotoAndStop("howtoplay");
        }

        private function gotoMenu(evt:MouseEvent)
        {
            btnBack.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoMenu);
            gotoAndStop("menu");
        }

        private function keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.A) 
            {
                //1st Player Left Key
                left = true;
            }
            else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
            {
                //1st Player Right Key
                right = true;
            }

            if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.W) 
            {
                //1st Player Up Key
                up = true;
            }
            else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
            {
                //1st Player Down Key
                down = true;
            }

            if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) 
            {
                spacePressed = true;

            }           



        }

        private function keyUpHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.A)
            {
                left = false;
            }
            else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
            {
                right = false;
            }
            else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
            {
                up = false;
            }
            else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
            {
                down = false;
            }

            if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) 
            {
                spacePressed = false;
            }


        }


        public function update(evt:Event)
        {
            handleUserInput();
            handleGameLogic();
            handleDraw();

            if (gotoWin)
                triggerGoToWin();
            else if (gotoLose)
                triggerGoToLose();
        }

        private function handleUserInput()
        {
            //Handle player 1 position

            //if player wants to move left but snake is not
            //already moving right
            if (left && (p1speedX != 1)) 
            {
                p1speedX = -1;
                p1speedY = 0;
            }
            //if player wants to move right but snake is not
            //already moving left
            else if (right && (p1speedX != -1 ))
            {
                p1speedX = 1;
                p1speedY = 0;
            }
            //if player wants to move up but snake is not
            //already moving down
            else if (up && (p1speedY != 1))
            {
                p1speedY = -1;
                p1speedX = 0;
            }
            else if (down && (p1speedY != -1))
            {
                p1speedY = 1;
                p1speedX = 0;
            }

            if (spacePressed)
                readyToMove = true;

        }

        private function handleGameLogic()
        {
            if (!readyToMove)
                return;

            framesElapsed++;

            //Update the new position of the snake's head
            if (framesElapsed % 2 == 0)
            {
                //Update motion of the snake's body
                for (var i = snakes.length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
                {
                    snakes[i].x = snakes[i-1].x;
                    snakes[i].y = snakes[i-1].y;
                }

                if (p1speedX > 0)
                {
                    snakes[0].x += 20;
                }
                else if (p1speedX < 0)
                {
                    snakes[0].x -= 20;
                }
                else if (p1speedY > 0)
                {
                    snakes[0].y += 20;
                }
                else if (p1speedY < 0)
                {
                    snakes[0].y -= 20;
                }

                //Check for collisions between the snake and its own body
                for (var i = snakes.length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
                {
                    if ((snakes[0].x == snakes[i].x) &&
                        (snakes[0].y == snakes[i].y))
                    {
                        collided();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Check for collisions between the snake and the walls
            if (snakes[0].y < 0)
            {
                collided();
            }
            else if (snakes[0].x > 800)
            {
                collided();
            }
            else if (snakes[0].x < 0)
            {
                collided();
            }
            else if (snakes[0].y > 600)
            {
                collided();
            }

            //Add new food items
            if (mcFood == null)
            {
                //Create a new food item
                mcFood = new Food();
                mcFood.x = Math.random() * 700 + 50;
                mcFood.y = Math.random() * 500 + 50;
                addChild(mcFood);
            }

            //Check for collisions between food item and Snake
            if (mcFood != null)
            {
                if (snakes[0].hitTestObject(mcFood))
                {
                    //Add score
                    score += 100;
                    if (score >= 5000)
                        gotoWin = true;

                    removeChild(mcFood);
                    mcFood = null;

                    //Add a body
                    var newPart = new SnakePart();
                    newPart.x = snakes[snakes.length-1].x;
                    newPart.y = snakes[snakes.length-1].y;
                    snakes.push(newPart);
                    addChild(newPart);
                }
            }
        }

        private function handleDraw()
        {
            //Handle display
            if (!readyToMove)
                txtHitSpaceBar.visible = true;
            else
                txtHitSpaceBar.visible = false;

            txtScoreP1.text = String(score);
            txtLife.text = String(life);
        }

        private function triggerGoToWin()
        {
            clearGame();
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            gotoAndStop("win");
        }

        private function triggerGoToLose()
        {
            clearGame();
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            gotoAndStop("lose");
        }

        //Misc Functions
        private function resetGame()
        {
            //remove all food
            removeChild(mcFood);
            mcFood = null;

            //remove all of snake body except first
            for (var i = snakes.length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                removeChild(snakes[i]);
                snakes.splice(i,1);
            }

            //Center the snake's head
            snakes[0].x = 400;
            snakes[0].y = 300;

            readyToMove = false;
        }

        private function clearGame()
        {
            //remove all food
            if (mcFood != null)
            {
                removeChild(mcFood);
                mcFood = null;
            }

            //remove all of snake body
            for (var i = snakes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                removeChild(snakes[i]);
                snakes.splice(i,1);
            }
        }

        private function collided()
        {
            life -= 1;

            if (life > 0)
                resetGame();
            else
                gotoLose = true;
        }




            }

    }//end class    
//end package
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities how to pause a game.

You already have a boolean variable called `_Paused`, this will help us to determine when to pause the execution of the game.

Change the contents of `keyDownHandler(evt)` to the following:

```
private function keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        ...
        //leave the if conditionals for movement as they are
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) 
        {
            if(_Pause == true){
                _Pause = false;
            }else{
                _Pause = true;
            }
        }           
    }
```

The above code will toggle between a Paused state and the Game state. When the game first starts, the `_Paused` variable is `false`. Once you press Space on your keyboard, the if condition will check what state you need to be in. So at the very first time, `_Paused` will be set to `true`. if you press space again, it will set it to `false` again. Simple, right?

Now, you have an EventListener for `ENTER_FRAME` called `update` that executes for every frame. This function is responsible that things, well, work. You can see that it calls different functions that draw stuff on the screen or handle game logic. So, what would happen if you don't call this function? The game would stop. So we need a way to not call those functions when you are in your pause state. Again, this is very simple.

Change the contents of `update(evt)` to the following:

```
public function update(evt:Event)
    {
        if(_Paused == false){
           handleUserInput();
           handleGameLogic();
           handleDraw();

           if (gotoWin)
              triggerGoToWin();
           else if (gotoLose)
              triggerGoToLose();
        }
    }
```

Now the functions will only be called when your `_Paused` variable is set to false.
I hope this helped you with your studying, although this is very basic stuff. Maybe you should try smaller steps first? Programming games can be pretty complex for beginner who have no experience with coding whatsoever.